# Go Lang- Appending a struct to a slice

Tags: go

Is it Possible to append a `struct` to a `slice`? Can anyone please post an example?
This `slice` needs to have `struct` values.

```
testSlice = make([]Row, 10)
```

I tried appending this way but it did not work.

```
testSlice.append(row)
```

Comment: The correct syntax for [append](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) is: `testSlice = append(testSlice, row)`. Please take the [go tour](https://tour.golang.org).

Comment: Thank you. that was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`testSlice = append(testSlice, Row{/*...*/})`